# .net async abnormal behavior

Tags: .net, asynchronous, synchronization, async-await

I have an abnormal behavior on WPF MainWindow ctor. I am using an asynchronous method to make a long task, but this task named 'DoAsync' is not complete ! I found a workaround but i don't understood why the code fails :( Here the two calls and the results :

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static void WriteToOutput(string message, int increment = 0)
    {
        var nw = DateTime.Now;
        var msg = string.Format("{0}.{1:d3} - thread {2:d1}[0x{3:x4}] |\t{4}{5}",
                                    nw.ToString("hh:mm:ss"),
                                    nw.Millisecond,
                                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                    AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId(),
                                    new string(' ', 4 * increment),
                                    message
                                );

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    public async Task DoAsync()
    {
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: begin", 2);
        await Task.Delay(1);                    // enforces asynchronism
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job begin", 3);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);    // simulates some job ;)
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job end", 3);
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: end", 2);
    }

    private void NormalBehavior()
    {
        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: begin", 0);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin", 1);
            await DoAsync();
            WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior_DoAsync: end", 1);
        });

        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: sleeping", 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);       // to see what happens
        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: terminated", 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Seems the simplest solution, but it fails :( Why ?
    /// </summary>
    private void AbnormalBehavior()
    {
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: begin", 0);

        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin", 1);
        var tsk = DoAsync();
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: end", 1);

        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: sleeping", 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);       // to see what happens
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: terminated", 0);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        NormalBehavior();
        //  Output:
        //  05:18:00.833 - thread 8[0x3818] |   NormalBehavior: begin
        //  05:18:00.842 - thread 8[0x3818] |   NormalBehavior: sleeping
        //  05:18:00.846 - thread 9[0x2274] |       NormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin
        //  05:18:00.848 - thread 9[0x2274] |           DoAsync: begin
        //  05:18:00.853 - thread 10[0x0778] |              DoAsync: job begin
        //  05:18:05.855 - thread 10[0x0778] |              DoAsync: job end
        //  05:18:05.856 - thread 10[0x0778] |          DoAsync: end
        //  05:18:05.856 - thread 10[0x0778] |      NormalBehavior_DoAsync: end
        //  05:18:10.843 - thread 8[0x3818] |   NormalBehavior: terminated
        //_________________________________________________________________

        AbnormalBehavior();
        //  Output:
        //  05:18:10.845 - thread 8[0x3818] |   AbnormalBehavior: begin
        //  05:18:10.846 - thread 8[0x3818] |       AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin
        //  05:18:10.847 - thread 8[0x3818] |           DoAsync: begin
        //  05:18:10.849 - thread 8[0x3818] |       AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: end
        //  05:18:10.850 - thread 8[0x3818] |   AbnormalBehavior: sleeping
        //  05:18:20.853 - thread 8[0x3818] |   AbnormalBehavior: terminated
        //_________________________________________________________________

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Anybody already found this problem or has an explanation ?

Comment: Because you are not asking for a result. Make `var tsk = DoAsync(); tsk.Result`.

Answer (score 1):

If you let it run longer, I expect you'll see `DoWork`'s "job begin" and other messages in your debug window.

This is expected behavior for `async`/`await`. In particular, `await` will capture the current "context" - which in the "abnormal" case is the UI context - and will resume on that context. I explain the [mechanics of `async`/`await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) in more detail on my blog.

The other thing of note with this code is that `Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread. In particular, when `Thread.Sleep` runs on the UI thread, that thread is blocked, and cannot execute other code.

`Task.Run` will execute the specified code on a thread pool thread, where there is no UI context, and any `await` in that case will resume on a thread pool thread.

Thus, with your first ("working") example, `DoAsync` runs on a thread pool thread and blocks a thread pool thread for 5 seconds. In the meantime, `NormalBehavior` blocks the UI thread for 10 seconds.

With the second ("failing") example, `AbnormalBehavior` runs `DoAsync` on the UI thread. As soon as `DoAsync` hits its `await`, `AbnormalBehavior` continues running and blocks the UI thread for 10 seconds. Only then is `DoAsync` able to resume on the UI thread and block it for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen you are right, after the 'AbnormalBehavior' last sleep I can see "DoAsync: job begin" & "DoAsync: job end" all done by the main thread ! 
Effectively it's the same thread (main thread) which do all the work and as you say it can't do the 'job' while it's sleeping :|
Even more, same code is running as I expected on a console program ! As you see in this case it's an other thread (worker thread) which do the job ! Perhaps because it doesn't need to capture the context !?

```
class Program
{
    static DateTime _Start = new DateTime(0);

    static void WriteToOutput(string message, int increment = 0, bool start = false)
    {
        var nw = DateTime.Now;
        if (start) _Start = nw;
        var spn = nw - _Start;

        var msg = string.Format("{0,2:d}.{1:d3} - thread {2,2:d1}[0x{3:x4}] |\t{4}{5}",
                                    (int)Math.Floor(spn.TotalSeconds),
                                    spn.Milliseconds,
                                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                    AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId(),
                                    new string(' ', 4 * increment),
                                    message
                                );

        if (start) msg = "\n" + msg;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    public static async Task DoAsync()
    {
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: begin", 2);
        await Task.Delay(1);                    // enforces asynchronism
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job begin", 3);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);    // simulates some job ;)
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job end", 3);
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: end", 2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// It works correctly but it uses more resources and run more slowly :o
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Task DoRescueAsync()
    {
        WriteToOutput("DoAsync: begin", 2);
        return Task.Run(() => {
            WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job begin", 3);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);    // simulates some job ;)
            WriteToOutput("DoAsync: job end", 3);
            WriteToOutput("DoAsync: end", 2);
        });
    }

    private static void NormalBehavior()
    {
        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: begin", 0, true);

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin", 1);
            await DoAsync();
            WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior_DoAsync: end", 1);
        });

        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: sleeping", 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);       // to see what happens
        WriteToOutput("NormalBehavior: terminated", 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Seems the simplest solution, but it fails :( Why ?
    /// </summary>
    private static void AbnormalBehavior()
    {
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: begin", 0, true);

        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin", 1);
        var tsk = DoAsync();
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: end", 1);

        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: sleeping", 0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);       // to see what happens
        WriteToOutput("AbnormalBehavior: terminated", 0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NormalBehavior();
        // Output:
        //   0.000 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    NormalBehavior: begin
        //   0.014 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    NormalBehavior: sleeping
        //   0.019 - thread  3[0x0bdc] |        NormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin
        //   0.024 - thread  3[0x0bdc] |            DoAsync: begin
        //   0.029 - thread  4[0x1568] |                DoAsync: job begin
        //   5.045 - thread  4[0x1568] |                DoAsync: job end
        //   5.050 - thread  4[0x1568] |            DoAsync: end
        //   5.053 - thread  4[0x1568] |        NormalBehavior_DoAsync: end
        //  10.018 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    NormalBehavior: terminated
        //_________________________________________________________________

        AbnormalBehavior();     // now CORRECT as expected !
        // Output:
        // 0.000 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    AbnormalBehavior: begin
        // 0.008 - thread  1[0x34cc] |        AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: begin
        // 0.029 - thread  1[0x34cc] |            DoAsync: begin
        // 0.037 - thread  1[0x34cc] |        AbnormalBehavior_DoAsync: end
        // 0.043 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    AbnormalBehavior: sleeping
        // 0.047 - thread  3[0x0bdc] |                DoAsync: job begin
        // 5.062 - thread  3[0x0bdc] |                DoAsync: job end
        // 7.306 - thread  3[0x0bdc] |            DoAsync: end
        //10.057 - thread  1[0x34cc] |    AbnormalBehavior: terminated
        //_________________________________________________________________

        Console.Write("\nHit a key to close console: "); Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```